# jpegrecompress worker: `jpeg-recompress` not found;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I recently installed the [paperclip-optimizer](https://github.com/janfoeh/paperclip-optimizer) gem in my Rails 4 app on Heroku. Whenever I attempt to save an uploaded image attachment, I get the following error: `jpegrecompress worker: 'jpeg-recompress' not found;` in my logs from Heroku, but not on localhost.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I can't seem to find a single StackOverflow post, blog post, or other resource on this problem.

Here is my `config/initializers/paperclip_optimizer.rb`:

```
Paperclip::PaperclipOptimizer.default_options = {
    skip_missing_workers: true,
    advpng: false,
    gifsicle: false,
    jhead: false,
    jpegoptim: false,
    jpegrecompress: true,
    jpegtran: false,
    optipng: false,
    pngcrush: false,
    pngout: false,
    pngquant: true,
    svgo: false,
    nice: 10,             # Nice level (defaults to 10)
    threads: 1,           # Number of threads or disable (defaults to number of processors)
    verbose: false,       # Verbose output (defaults to false)
    pack: nil,            # Require image_optim_pack or disable it, by default image_optim_pack will be used if available,
    allow_lossy: true,   # Allow lossy workers and optimizations (defaults to false)
    jpegrecompress: {
        quality: 2          # JPEG quality preset: 0 - low, 1 - medium, 2 - high, 3 - veryhigh (defaults to 3)
    },
    pngquant: {
        quality: 100..100,  # min..max - don't save below min, use less colors below max (both in range 0..100; in yaml - !ruby/range 0..100) (defaults to 100..100)
        speed: 3            # speed/quality trade-off: 1 - slow, 3 - default, 11 - fast & rough (defaults to 3)
    }
}
```

In my `photo.rb` model I have:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "", processors: [:thumbnail, :paperclip_optimizer]
```

In my `.buildpacks` file for Heroku I have:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack.git
```

I added the Ruby buildpack to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482945/heroku-buildpack-multi-causing-app-to-crash) I was having earlier, but now it seems as though the multi and the image-optim buildpacks aren't loading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head banging and keyboard bashing, I figured out how to solve the problem. In my case, I'm running a Rails 4.0 app on the `Cedar-14` stack running on the `Puma` webserver, so these instructions may or may not be of use to you if you're configuration is different.

1. I followed the steps on this [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) article on adding multiple buildpacks to an app, which is now supported by Heroku.
   In my case, I have the following buildpacks added for my app:

   ```
   === staging-app Buildpack URLs
   1. https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack.git
   2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
   ```

   The order is critical. The last buildpack on the list is the first one to be loaded. In my case, I need the Ruby buildpack so that the `bundle` command in my Procfile is recognized. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482945/heroku-buildpack-multi-causing-app-to-crash) for more on that issue.
2. Do NOT use the [Heroku-Buildpack-Multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). From what I understand, this is the old way to support multiple buildpacks. Adding this will cause your pushes to be rejected.
3. In my Gemfile, I needed to include the [image_optim](https://github.com/toy/image_optim) and [image_optim_pack](https://github.com/toy/image_optim_pack) gems. These gems make the appropriate binaries available on OS X and Linux environments, from what I understand. It is very important to place these gems before `paperclip-optimizer` in the Gemfile, like so

   ```
   gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
   group :production do
       # Needs to be placed before paperclip-optimizer
       gem 'image_optim'
       gem 'image_optim_pack'
   end
   gem 'paperclip-optimizer'
   ```
4. Configure your `paperclip-optimizer` settings as you see fit and push to production.

Hopefully this helps someone in my situation.