# Heroku-Buildpack-Multi causing app to crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, buildpack

I'm have a Rails 4 app on Heroku that I'm trying to deploy with two buildpacks. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step or if there is a bug, but when I push the code, the app deploys successfully. When I open it however, it crashes.

I've tried using the command `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack.git` and `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`, but am only able to set one at a time, not both. It doesn't seem to matter which one I set, the app always crashes. Searching through the logs, I see the following:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm no expert on `bundler`, but it seems like for some reason it's not recognizing the bundle command in my Procfile.

Here is my Procfile, which I should note has worked perfectly up until now.

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

I've also tried clearing out the buildpacks (`heroku buildpacks:clear`) and creating a `.buildpacks` file instead, but that yielded the same error.

Here is my `.builcpacks` file:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
https://github.com/bobbus/image-optim-buildpack.git
```

The documentation in the Heroku Dev Center and on the buildpacks themselves is pretty sparse as far as I can tell.

Comment: Would you please clarify this "has worked perfectly up until now." Was the bundle command working on Heroku deploy at one point, then something broke it?

Comment: The bundle command in my Procfile was working fine before and will still work if I delete the .buildpacks file and/or run `heroku buildpacks:clear`. The error in the log leads me to believe that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Okay. That's helpful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two build packs you listed are the only two you're loading, I think  you're missing the Ruby buildpack, which is where the "bundler" is defined:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

**Note:**  If I were debugging this, I would ditch the buildpack-multi, and use just the Ruby buildpack to see if you can get that through the bundler error, then try to load another buildpack, and so on.

---

I see what you mean about the documentation. Pretty weak. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have solved my app crashing problem. I'm still not having any luck with the buildpacks I need though. When I run `heroku buildpacks` nothing shows up.

Comment: I'm not a buildpack expert  (I moved off Heroku a while ago), but I can throw some ideas at you...when I run $heroku buildpacks on my app it responds "appname has no Buildpack URL set." Which is true. What message do you get, if any?

Comment: I'm actually no longer using  `heroku-buildpack-multi`. I ran into more problems with it before realizing that the source of my problems it seems is that Heroku supports multiple buildpacks natively now. So whenever I tried adding the multi pack with other packs, it caused my app to crash or fail to deploy. I had posted a question on the subject as well as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467247/jpegrecompress-worker-jpeg-recompress-not-found). The resources I found on buildpacks, even from Heroku, are not terribly helpful.

Comment: Yes. Seems like a good idea to steer towards the Heroku-supplied buildpacks. The documentation there is better than the -buildpack-multi, which was essentially *no documentation*. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the .buildpacks multi manager isnt required because Heroku supports multiple buildpacks natively by passing --index when setting a buildpack for example:

- heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby --index 1
- heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg --index 2
- Change something in your git repo && then do a -> git push heroku master

The Deploy will detect your buildpacks and will run them. To check what buildpacks are currently set in your app run: heroku buildpacks

Comment: This did the job for me, nice.